# Can someone tell me what LaTeX typeface this is?

Tags: fonts

It's the font used for the examples on the Texpad website, it's not one of the default fonts, but I can't seem to find what it is. I'm hoping someone would recognise it, thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're showing a screenshot of the code -- can you maybe scroll up a bit more and examine the contents of the preamble?

Comment: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)

Comment: You can surely find the font packages loaded in the preamble.

Comment: Looks like Libertine to me.

Comment: The screenshots are taken from the Texpad app web site, so it is not possible to scroll up to see the preamble. There another screenshot  with at preamble, but it calls a custom thesis class (which is not available), and there are no font packages in that preamble.  Anyway, to me it look like Bitstream Charter (shape of the b, and W, g, a, e )

Comment: Can't you just ask the people who run the site? We can only offer (informed) guesses...

Comment: I asked a few weeks ago, there was no response...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is Kepler (aka [`kpfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/kpfonts/)).  For some more verification compare the following output to the first image in your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
The lack of Weyl classical invariance may be compensated by one-loop
contributions arising from couplings to $G_{\mu\nu}$ and
$B_{\mu\nu}$. The beta functions associated with $G_{\mu\nu}$,
$B_{\mu\nu}$ and $\phi(X)$ at the one loop level are
\begin{align}
  \beta_{\mu\nu}(G) &= \alpha' R_{\mu\nu} + 2 \alpha' \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi
  + \frac{\alpha'}{4} H_{\mu\lambda\rho} H_\nu^{\lambda\rho} \\
  \beta_{\mu\nu}(B) &= - \frac{\alpha'}{2} \nabla^\lambda H_{\lambda\mu\nu}
  + \alpha' \nabla^\lambda \phi H_{\lambda\mu\nu} \\
  \beta(\phi) &= \frac{D-26}{6} - \frac{\alpha'}{2} \nabla^2 \phi
  + \alpha' \nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi - \frac{\alpha'}{24} H_{\lambda\mu\nu} H^{\lambda\mu\nu}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]